# Fastest way to get random php number?

Tags: php

I'm trying to prevent caching by appending a '? t=' to the end of my JS files. What's the fastest way to get such a number? time() or rand() or something else?

Comment: Fastest meaning least resource intensive.

Comment: Why are you so concerned about speed with this particular operation?  Have you profiled?  How much time do you expect to save by choosing one over the other?  ...allow me to be more direct: it doesn't make a meaningful difference.  We're talking a difference measured in nanoseconds.

Comment: @Frank Farmer: It's still fun to talk about. :)

Comment: 22 million page views per day, each with 6 uncacheable files. So even nanoseconds eventually makes a difference

Comment: 6 * 22 million * 10 nanoseconds = 1.32 seconds. Not that much amortized over a day.

Comment: @Shrapnel I agree, he is bad with numbers, but I disagree, the question is not stupid. And I don't see any reason to get personal like that.

Comment: Note that these functions fulfill different characteristics: `time` returns “unique” values while `rand` returns random values. But uniqueness is not the same as randomness.

Comment: It looks like, for the asker's purpose, uniqueness is the ultimate goal.

Comment: If you want to make sure the cached version is correct, try appending a hash to the end instead of a random value. There's usually no point serving a file with identical contents if it's been cached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`time()` and `mt_rand()` are pretty similar in terms of efficiency in PHP - you select one or the other based on what factors you need it for:

- Just hard to guess: use `mt_rand()` (e.g., generating use salt)
- Get a unique identifier that is hard to guess: use `mt_rand(1, 931415926536);` (e.g., generating session id)
- (obviously) keep records: use `time()` (e.g., prevent caching, logs etc)

If you really want to know, `time()` is *slightly* faster—but you really don't need to worry about it. (It's the difference between one or two small parts of a second.)

Note that `rand()` is now an alias to `mt_rand()` since PHP 7.1:

> rand() and srand() have now been made aliases to mt_rand() and mt_srand(), respectively. This means that the output for the following functions have changed: rand(), shuffle(), str_shuffle(), and array_rand().

You probably know this already, but be sure to always profile your code before making optimizations; often it'll run slowly for reasons completely different than what you expected.

Comment: time() is slightly faster than? Rand or mtrand?

Comment: time() is slightly faster than both. Plus, for cache control there is a small possibility that you'll generate the same random number twice; this is not the case (unless your machine is very fast and you have multiple requests per second) for time().

Comment: Using `mt_rand(1, time())` makes no sense. All that you're doing with that is adding an extra function call and reducing the range of possible numbers (making it more likely for a collision).

Comment: just call `mt_rand()` without parameters

Comment: Just to update this after ~4 years.  time() is the slowest in my tests, followed by mt_rand() and rand() is the fastest.  Looks like it has been improved over the years.  I tested in on my server and found rand() to be the fastest every time.  Also found similar results using PHP 5.5 here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a17d7d79434a9b91870e78fff432cfd356388bd2

Answer (score 6):

Call me old-fashioned, but preventing caching is something that can and should be achieved by using HTTP headers, not unique URLs. If you serve the file dynamically through PHP:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

otherwise use a .htaccess file in apache (or similar config in any other web server):

```
<FilesMatch "\.js$">
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate"
Header set Expires "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're only preventing caching, time() would be sufficient.

Comment: Is that more efficient than rand or mt_rand?

Comment: Without any testing or spesification to back up my claim, I dare say yes.

Comment: I don't really know how the time function works to figure out the number of seconds, but I'd assume it'd be faster than running a random number algorithm, probably not by much though. It does, however, guarantee that you'll never get a repeat result which is possible using a random number function.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `rand()`, use [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand).

> It uses a random number generator with known characteristics using the [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html), which will produce random numbers **four times faster** than what the average libc rand() provides.

Comment: could you guys quit bullying around? the question is not stupid, nor is this answer. grow up

Comment: for some time now rand and mt_rand are synonymous. differences are due to server load.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
'?t=' . mt_rand(time());
```

Comment: Why not just `time()`? Choosing a random number between 1 and time makes it slower... I don't think he wanted to combine them, he just wants the least impact choice.

Comment: @animuson: Yes, good point, updated `mt_rand` is better choice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

this is a bit old but here is a time comparison for 10 million Execution

Total Execution Time Test mt_rand : 0.0067805965741475 Mins

Total Execution Time Test rand : 0.0068778196970622 Mins

Total Execution Time Test time : 0.0088921149571737 Mins

it looks like mt_rand is slightly faster.

```
$i=10000000;
$time_start_1 = microtime(true); 
//test script 1
while($i--) {
    mt_rand(1,100);
}
$time_end_1 = microtime(true);


$i=10000000;
$time_start_2 = microtime(true); 
//test script 2
while($i--) {
    rand(1,100);
}
$time_end_2 = microtime(true);

$i=10000000;
$time_start_3 = microtime(true); 
//test script 3
while($i--) {
    time();
}
$time_end_3 = microtime(true);

//dividing with 60 will give the execution time in minutes otherwise seconds
$execution_time_1 = ($time_end_1 - $time_start_1); //   /60
$execution_time_2 = ($time_end_2 - $time_start_2); //   /60
$execution_time_3 = ($time_end_3 - $time_start_3); //   /60

//execution time of the script
echo '<br>';
echo '<b>Total Execution Time Test mt_rand :</b> '.($execution_time_1/60).' Mins'.'<br>';
echo '<b>Total Execution Time Test rand :</b> '.($execution_time_2/60).' Mins'.'<br>';
echo '<b>Total Execution Time Test time :</b> '.($execution_time_3/60).' Mins'.'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
srand(time());
echo '?t=' . rand();
```

Comment: This isn't any more random than time(), as it wil provide the same semi random number for 1 second at the time.

Comment: While that is true, the author's use case is only in preventing caching of JS resources. In this case I think this to be a reasonable solution.