# Fastest way to generate and check numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, numbers

I need some help with generating numbers in PHP then checking for example if that number is below a hundred give 0.1 points. This is for a coins system that will be called when certain actions in a flash game are used.

I want to do this in the fastest time possible and here is the code I'm using to test it before I update it to the main server for the game.

```
<?php
$coins = 0;
$rand = rand(0, 1000);

if($rand < 50){
$coins = $coins + 0.01;
}

if($rand < 100 && $rand > 50){
$coins = $coins + 0.2;
}

if($rand > 100 && $rand < 200){
$coins = $coins + 0.2;
}

if($rand > 500){
$coins = $coins + 0.5;
}

echo "Generated $coins coins \n";
?>
```

Sorry if anyone does not understand my quest in a few words I'm asking how could I make this faster and does anyone have any tips for it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `rand()`, consider using [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand). From the docs:

> Many random number generators of older libcs have dubious or unknown
>   characteristics and are slow. By default, PHP uses the libc random
>   number generator with the rand() function. The mt_rand() function is a
>   drop-in replacement for this. It uses a random number generator with
>   known characteristics using the »  Mersenne Twister, which will
>   produce random numbers **four times faster than what the average libc
>   rand() provides**.

Also, here's another very similar thread discussing the same topic: [Fastest way to get random php number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107342/fastest-way-to-get-random-php-number)

I am not sure what kind of optimizing you're seeking here though and would like to reiterate Frank Farmer's comment from that discussion:

> Why are you so concerned about speed with this particular operation?
>   Have you profiled? How much time do you expect to save by choosing one
>   over the other? ...allow me to be more direct: it doesn't make a
>   meaningful difference. We're talking a difference measured in
>   nanoseconds

Comment: Thanks i will look into using mt_rand() and the reason why speed matters so much here is because this code will be called upon serveral thousand times in short spaces of time.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is use else such that you're not executing every test every time. I.e., if you do this:

```
if (condition1) ...
if (condition2) ...
if (condition3) ...
```

Then PHP will have to perform the check for each condition every time. If you know that condition1 excludes condition2, then do this:

```
if (condition1) ...
elseif (condition2) ...
elseif (condition3) ...
```

This way, you only execute the conditions up to the point where you actually get a match. The next step would be to put the most-likely-to-succeed condition first:

```
if ($rand > 500) ...
elseif ($rand > 100 && $rand < 200) ...
```

This way, half the time, you're only ever doing one check.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check both `>` and `<` if you chain your comparisons together like so:

```
<?php
$coins = 0;
$rand = rand(0, 1000);

if( $rand > 500 ) {
    $coins += 0.5;
} else if( $rand > 200 ) {
    $coins += 0.4;
} else if( $rand > 100 ) {
    $coins += 0.3;
} else if( $rand > 50 ) {
    $coins += 0.2;
} else {
    $coins += 0.1;
}

echo "Generated $coins coins \n";
```

And unless you're going to loop this, or your original code millions of time per second I wouldn't worry about it.

What I *would* worry about, however, is the overhead to call this script via HTTP every time something happens in your flash game. That overhead is what will decrease performance in your game, and put load on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i won't be calling the script via http i will be using a tcp socket server.